# How to save the active "Word" document in VBScript?

Tags: vbscript, automation, ms-word

Here I have a small VBS script that helps me append a new line to a table in MS "Word" 2003:

```
Set wd = CreateObject("Word.Application")

wd.Visible = True

Set doc = wd.Documents.Open ("c:\addtotable.doc")

Set r = doc.Tables(1).Rows.Add

aa = Split("turtle,dog,rooster,maple", ",")

For i = 0 To r.Cells.Count - 1
  r.Cells(i + 1).Range.Text = aa(i)
Next
```

It works fine, but it doesn't save anything. I want it to save the performed changes.

By the method of macro-recording in the "Word" I got this macro command that saves active "Word" document:

```
ActiveDocument.Save
```

So, I decided to append this macro to the VBS script above:

```
 Set wd = CreateObject("Word.Application")

    wd.Visible = True

    Set doc = wd.Documents.Open ("c:\addtotable.doc")

    Set r = doc.Tables(1).Rows.Add

    aa = Split("turtle,dog,rooster,maple", ",")

    For i = 0 To r.Cells.Count - 1
      r.Cells(i + 1).Range.Text = aa(i)
    Next

     ActiveDocument.Save
```

But it doesn't save anything. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you already tried calling `doc.Save` after making those changes? If that doesn't work:

The issue is that `ActiveDocument` doesn't automatically reference what you think it does in VBScript the way it does in Word's VBA.

Try setting a new variable to the active document, like so:

```
Dim activeDoc
Set activeDoc = wd.ActiveDocument
activeDoc.Save
```

Comment: Thanks AndreiM. Now it does exactly what I want!

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to use `ActiveDocument.SaveAs("C:\addtotable.doc");` because I can't find any documentation for `.Save`.  `SaveAs` accepts a second parameter which specifies what format to save it in.  Pastebin of the parameters **[here](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=fPi9mVjZ)**.